# WP_Query не фильтрует посты по метаполям

Tags: php, wordpress

Запрос выводит все посты указанного типа, но никак не реагирует на значение метаполей. Как сделать что бы выводились посты с учетом значений метаполей?

```
    <?php 
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'post_type',
    'sentence' => 1,
    'meta_query' => array(
 'relation' => 'AND',
 array(
 'key'     => 'publisher',
 'value'   => 'publisher',
 'compare' => '=',
     ),
        array(
 'key'     => 'creator',
 'value'   => 'creator',
 'compare' => '=',
     ),
        array(
 'key'     => 'year',
 'value'   => '1996',
 'compare' => '=',
     ),
 ),
);

$posts = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( ( $posts->have_posts() ) ) : ?>
        //posts
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php else: ?>
      //some code
    <?php
    endif; 
?>
```

Comment: Зачем там параметр `'sentence'`? Что-то я не вижу там поиска. А у Вас так и указано в мета поле `'creator'` значение равно `'creator'`, тоже самое касается и publisher и есть какая-то запись, которая удовлетворяет всем трем условиям, где `'publisher' = 'publisher'`, `'creator' = 'creator'` и `'year' = '1996'`.

Comment: про sentense - на самом деле я делал расширенный поиск, но он не работает, поэтому я решил упростить код для того что бы понять в чем проблема (а sentense пропустил при копировании). но такой код тоже не выводит то что нужно. запись с соответствующими полями/значениями есть

Comment: А Вы года так и храните текстовым полем или там Data Picker от ACF, например?

Comment: да, они просто текстом записаны

Comment: Ну тогда здесь нет ошибки, если все вышестоящие условия выполнены.

Comment: Я тоже думал что все верно ,но тем не менее код не работает

Comment: А вы пробовали данный код, но при меньших условиях фильтрации?

Comment: я уже столько всего перепробовал что не помню пробовал ли это. Но обязательно попробую, хотя без особого оптимизма